# Use one entity in two contexts in Entity Framework 6+

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have one entity like this:

```
public class AppUser 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and an `AppContext`:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and an `UserContext`:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
}
```

In package manager console (in project that include `UserContext`):

```
add-migrations initial
update-database
```

it's ok, but in package manager console (in project that includes `ApplicationContext`):

```
add-migration Initial
update-database
```

throws an error message like this :

> AppUser already exists in database!

How can I use (share) `AppUser` entity in two contexts?

Comment: Why using two contexts with same DbSet<AppUser>?

Comment: Two contexts can contain the same entity, but if you want to use migrations, One DBContext will need to "own" the entities, meaning the other context will need to be set up as DB First, no migration.